# Related tags don't have thousands separators

Tags: bug, tags, formatting

The tagged questions pages (for [example](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests)) show a count of questions at the top, like "8,279 questions tagged".

Below is a list of related tags, and their counts. However, the counts are missing commas as thousands separators.

[image: tags with counts like 1203]

Should the related tag counts also have thousands separators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, for consistency, these numbers should also use thousands separators.

As the main SE language is English, even for sites about other languages such Russian, then a comma should be used as the separator.

Other parts also use thousands separators, like stats, so tags should do so too. Here's some stats from Russian Language Stack Exchange:

[image: Stats from Russian SE that use commas]